# Encrypting an already zipped file

Tags: java, encryption

Is there a way where I can generate password for an already zipped file? I think I am clear here that the file is already been zipped. All I want is to pick the file and make it password protected.

Any help would be highly appreciated.Thanks

Comment: This is what you need http://java.sys-con.com/node/1258827

Comment: @AurA Not a duplicate - this question has the constraint that the file is already zipped.

Comment: Would there be a problem with just zipping it again, with a password?

Comment: No Duncan it wont be problem but it wont look good regarding client perspective thats why I emphasized on this.